How to align text inside of a SVG
I am attempting to show text within different sections of an SVG. Due to the curvature of the SVG, I was unable to do this without purchasing various plugins for the software used to generate the SVG (Most of the plugins also didn't provide the desired effect when free trials were used), so I turned to trying to resolve this with HTML and CSS. I found a similar thread which put me on the right path to getting the text within the bounds of the SVG paths but not to the desired locations.
Here is a snippet of the HTML and CSS I currently have:


path:hover {
  fill: #9F1F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg>text {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}
<svg width="540" height="540" viewBox="0 0 1260 1260" style="background: #f4f4f8;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="lorem-ipsum" d="M19.6535 473.868C47.9918 363.089 105.946 262.111 187.302 181.761C268.658 101.41 370.349 44.7167 481.472 17.7586L494.995 73.5011C393.989 98.0047 301.557 149.536 227.608 222.571C153.659 295.606 100.982 387.39 75.2235 488.083L19.6535 473.868Z" fill="#58585A" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-inside-1_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath style="color: #fff;" xlink:href="#lorem-ipsum" startOffset="310" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="dolor-sit" d="M943.948 453.828C974.447 508.179 990.314 569.517 989.995 631.839C989.677 694.162 973.184 755.334 942.132 809.371C911.079 863.407 866.529 908.456 812.843 940.11C759.156 971.764 698.172 988.938 635.857 989.952C573.542 990.966 512.03 975.785 457.343 945.895C402.655 916.004 356.663 872.428 323.869 819.43C291.075 766.433 272.601 705.829 270.255 643.55C267.909 581.271 281.772 519.449 310.487 464.135L354.36 486.91C329.588 534.629 317.629 587.962 319.653 641.689C321.676 695.417 337.614 747.699 365.905 793.419C394.196 839.14 433.872 876.732 481.051 902.518C528.229 928.304 581.294 941.401 635.053 940.526C688.811 939.652 741.422 924.836 787.736 897.528C834.051 870.221 872.483 831.357 899.272 784.741C926.061 738.124 940.289 685.352 940.563 631.587C940.838 577.822 927.15 524.907 900.839 478.019L943.948 453.828Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-6-inside-6_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#dolor-sit" startOffset="2175" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Dolor Sit
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="amet" d="M476.668 407.763C521.185 377.048 573.901 360.411 627.985 360.008C682.069 359.604 735.028 375.452 779.999 405.5L749.393 451.307C713.598 427.391 671.445 414.776 628.396 415.097C585.348 415.418 543.388 428.661 507.954 453.109L476.668 407.763Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-11-inside-11_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#amet" startOffset="160" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Amet
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>



I am expecting the text to be centred within the purple section of the SVG and I have tried using CSS position, margin, padding etc.


You have the paths masked by an unexisting mask, 2. The path you are using for the textPath is a filled path. In order to understand what is happening give your paths a color stroke (now is white) and fill="none". You'll see the text following the path


The three paths are all outlines of a stroke, therefor it becomes difficult to align the text inside or between the path outline.
Now that all you paths effectively are strokes, you can turn the path into one line/outline, and give them a stroke instead of a fill. The text elements with the textPath element will now align to the stroke.


a:hover use:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: Turquoise;
}

a:hover use:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: #9F1F;
}

svg text {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}
<svg width="540" height="540" viewBox="0 0 1260 1260" style="background: #f4f4f8;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="lorem-ipsum" d="M 60 514 C 88 403 146 302 227 222 C 309 141 410 85 521 58"
      fill="none" stroke-linecap="square" />
  </defs>
  <a href="#">
    <use href="#lorem-ipsum" stroke="white" stroke-width="80"  />
    <use href="#lorem-ipsum" stroke="#58585A" stroke-width="60" />
    <text>
      <textPath fill="white" href="#lorem-ipsum"
        startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle"
        dominant-baseline="central">Lorem Ipsum</textPath>
    </text>
  </a>
</svg>



How to convert the paths
To convert the path from an outline of a stroke to a single line/outline I did the following:

Copied the path (value of the d attribute) into https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/
Removed that last half of the path commands including the z
Moved the path down and to the right (Translate x/Translate y) so that there was space for a wide stroke + the extra wide stroke for the white "border".
(optional) Now that the viewBox was quite large (1260x1260) I could removed all the decimals (Number of decimals).

How to make hover work
It actually worked in Firefox, but to make it work in Chrome you can add a <a> element around the svg elements that need to change on hover.

This works, however the on hover effect no longer works even when changing the css to look at the "use" tag. Also, I could do with some guidance on how to update the svg path d attribute to make it shorter as my existing d attributes partnered with the "use" tags make some large segments (I have 12 of these segments with different radii)

Thanks for the updated answer @chrwahl, definitely a lot to work with. I did actually figure out the CSS by using "use[stroke^="#"]:hover" as the selector which seems to be working a treat.

This has worked beautifully, made some minor amendments to the final version of this though as there were some clipping issues with some of the boxes. I removed the stroke-linecap from each path element and removed the use tags which supplied the white border which don't work without the linecaps. I'm happy with the end result though. I think if I played around more with the positioning of each of the different boxes in the svg the full version of this would work great, but I've already spent too much time on this section of the site I'm building. Thanks for you help :)

As commented, the closed path structure of the segments rather complicates a centered alignment.
Quick fix (approximated offset)
However you can get close to the desired result by applying a startOffset="25%" – aligning text ~ to the center of each segment.
To move the labels inside the segment shapes you can add a dy baseline shift like so:


path:hover {
  fill: #9F1F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

text {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}

textPath{
  start-offset:5%
}
<svg width="540" height="540" viewBox="0 0 1260 1260" style="background: #f4f4f8;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="lorem-ipsum" d="M19.6535 473.868C47.9918 363.089 105.946 262.111 187.302 181.761C268.658 101.41 370.349 44.7167 481.472 17.7586L494.995 73.5011C393.989 98.0047 301.557 149.536 227.608 222.571C153.659 295.606 100.982 387.39 75.2235 488.083L19.6535 473.868Z" fill="#58585A" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" />
    <text dy="20pt">
        <textPath style="color: #fff;" xlink:href="#lorem-ipsum" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="dolor-sit" d="M943.948 453.828C974.447 508.179 990.314 569.517 989.995 631.839C989.677 694.162 973.184 755.334 942.132 809.371C911.079 863.407 866.529 908.456 812.843 940.11C759.156 971.764 698.172 988.938 635.857 989.952C573.542 990.966 512.03 975.785 457.343 945.895C402.655 916.004 356.663 872.428 323.869 819.43C291.075 766.433 272.601 705.829 270.255 643.55C267.909 581.271 281.772 519.449 310.487 464.135L354.36 486.91C329.588 534.629 317.629 587.962 319.653 641.689C321.676 695.417 337.614 747.699 365.905 793.419C394.196 839.14 433.872 876.732 481.051 902.518C528.229 928.304 581.294 941.401 635.053 940.526C688.811 939.652 741.422 924.836 787.736 897.528C834.051 870.221 872.483 831.357 899.272 784.741C926.061 738.124 940.289 685.352 940.563 631.587C940.838 577.822 927.15 524.907 900.839 478.019L943.948 453.828Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" />
    <text dy="20pt">
        <textPath xlink:href="#dolor-sit" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Dolor Sit
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="amet" d="M476.668 407.763C521.185 377.048 573.901 360.411 627.985 360.008C682.069 359.604 735.028 375.452 779.999 405.5L749.393 451.307C713.598 427.391 671.445 414.776 628.396 415.097C585.348 415.418 543.388 428.661 507.954 453.109L476.668 407.763Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" />
    <text dy="20pt">
        <textPath xlink:href="#amet" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Amet
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>



25% is based on the assumption we have approximately twice the path length using a closed path as compared to a single open path. Obviously, this is a quite sloppy approximation which doesn't work perfectly as the outer and inner arc lengths may differ more or less significantly based on the visual stroke-width of a chart segment (since the segments are hard-coded into path data outlines we don't really have a stroke-width)
Auto refactor paths via JavaScript
As explained by chrwahl: you should consider refactoring your paths to open stroked elements to facilitate a centered alignment.
Here is an experimental  JavaScript helper function converting hard-coded chart segment paths to more compact (based on elliptic A arcto commands) path data notation.


let svg = document.querySelector('svg')
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path')
let decimals = 1;


btnConvert.addEventListener('click', () => {
  convertPieSegs();
})


function convertPieSegs() {

  paths.forEach((path, i) => {

    //copy strokes for additional white stroke
    let clone = path.cloneNode()
    clone.id = path.id + '_bg';
    pathToArc(clone, true);
    svg.insertBefore(clone, path)


    //convert closed paths to strokes
    pathToArc(path, false);


    // find text paths
    let textPath = svg.querySelector(`textPath[*|href="#${path.id}"]`)
    if (textPath) textPath.setAttribute('startOffset', '50%')

    //show new svg markup
    out.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)

  })

}


function pathToArc(path, closedPath = false) {

  let pathData = path.getPathData({
    normalize: true
  })

  // collect lines
  let lines = []
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(path)
  let strokeWidthAtt = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('stroke-width'));

  /**
   * collect on-path points 
   * for drawing direction info
   */
  let M = {
    x: pathData[0].values[0],
    y: pathData[0].values[1]
  }
  let pts = []
  let xArr = []
  let yArr = []

  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let comPrev = i > 0 ? pathData[i - 1] : pathData[0];
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;

    // only for rawing direction analysis
    let pt = values.length ? {
      x: values[values.length - 2],
      y: values[values.length - 1]
    } : {
      x: M.x,
      y: M.y
    }
    pts.push(pt);
    xArr.push(pt.x)
    yArr.push(pt.y)

    if (type === 'L' || type === 'Z') {
      let p1 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrev.length - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrev.length - 1]
      }
      let p2 = type === 'Z' ? {
        x: pathData[0].values[0],
        y: pathData[0].values[1]
      } : {
        x: values[0],
        y: values[1]
      }

      let p1_str = JSON.stringify(p1)
      let p2_str = JSON.stringify(p2)

      // skip z closepaths if path is closed by end coordinates
      if (p1_str !== p2_str) {
        lines.push([p1, p2])
      }
    }
  })


  // not a donut chart arc segment
  if (lines.length > 2) {
    return false
  }


  /**
   * sloppily approximated path area based on 
   * final on-path points
   * via "shoelace-formula"
   * if path area is negative
   * drawing direction is counter clockwise
   */
  let isClockwise = polygonArea(pts, false) > 0;
  let minX = Math.min(...xArr)
  let maxX = Math.max(...xArr)
  let minY = Math.min(...yArr)
  let maxY = Math.max(...yArr)


  let bb = {
    x: minX,
    y: minY,
    width: maxX - minX,
    height: maxY - minY
  }
  let mid = {
    x: bb.x + bb.width / 2,
    y: bb.y + bb.height / 2
  }



  //find intersection
  if (lines.length > 1) {
    let [p1, p2, p3, p4] = [lines[0][0], lines[0][1], lines[1][0], lines[1][1]]

    // get center point to calculate radii
    let pCenter = checkLineIntersection(p1, p2, p3, p4, false)

    /**
     * sorting inner and outer points
     * by comparing radii
     */
    let r1 = getDistance(pCenter, p1)
    let r2 = getDistance(pCenter, p2)

    let ptI = r1 > r2 ? p2 : p1
    let ptO = r1 > r2 ? p1 : p2

    let ptI_2 = r1 > r2 ? p3 : p4
    let ptO_2 = r1 > r2 ? p4 : p3

    //+strokeWidthAtt/4;

    //radius
    let rOuter = Math.max(r1, r2)
    let rInner = Math.min(r1, r2)

    // get start and end angles
    let a1 = getAngle(pCenter, p1);
    let a2 = getAngle(pCenter, p4);




    // delta angle for large arc
    let aDelta = a1 < 0 && a2 < 0 && !isClockwise ? Math.abs(a2 + a1) : (a1 < a2 ? Math.abs(a2 + a1) : Math.abs(a2 - a1));

    //new arc  commands
    let largeArc = aDelta >= 180 ? 1 : 0;
    let sweep = isClockwise ? 1 : 0;

    // replace hardcoded closed path with single open path applying a stroke
    let strokeWidth = +(rOuter - rInner).toFixed(decimals) - strokeWidthAtt;


    //text path
    let ptMid = interpolate(ptO, ptI, 0.5, decimals)
    let ptMid_2 = interpolate(ptO_2, ptI_2, 0.5, decimals)
    let rMid = +getDistance(ptMid, pCenter).toFixed(3)


    // center of path is below arc center point
    let reverse = mid.y > pCenter.y && isClockwise ? true : false;

    let d;

    // render closed path or single stroked arc
    if (!closedPath) {

      /**
       *  new path data  
       *  reverse drawing direction to keep text upright
       */
      if (reverse) {
        sweep = sweep === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        d = `M ${ptMid.x} ${ptMid.y} A ${rMid} ${rMid} 0 ${largeArc} ${sweep} ${ptMid_2.x} ${ptMid_2.y}`
      } else {
        d = `M ${ptMid_2.x} ${ptMid_2.y} A ${rMid} ${rMid} 0 ${largeArc} ${sweep} ${ptMid.x} ${ptMid.y}`
      }

      // copy fill to stroke
      let stroke = path.getAttribute('fill');
      path.setAttribute('stroke', stroke)
      path.setAttribute('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
      path.setAttribute('fill', 'none')


    }
    //closed path shape
    else {
      //round
      rOuter = +rOuter.toFixed(decimals)
      rInner = +rInner.toFixed(decimals)

      d = `M ${+ptO_2.x.toFixed(decimals)} ${+ptO_2.y.toFixed(decimals)} A ${rOuter} ${rOuter} 0 ${largeArc} 1 ${ptO.x.toFixed(decimals)} ${+ptO.y.toFixed(decimals)} L ${+ptI.x.toFixed(decimals)} ${+ptI.y.toFixed(decimals)} A ${rInner} ${rInner} 0 ${largeArc} 0 ${+ptI_2.x.toFixed(decimals)} ${+ptI_2.y.toFixed(decimals)}z`
    }


    // replace pathdata
    path.setAttribute('d', d)

  }
}


function getDistance(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)
  );
}


// get angle helper
function getAngle(p1, p2) {
  let angle = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;
  return angle;
}

/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolate(p1, p2, t, decimals = 3) {
  return {
    x: +((p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x).toFixed(decimals),
    y: +((p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y).toFixed(decimals)
  };
}


function polygonArea(points, absolute = true) {
  let area = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    const addX = points[i].x;
    const addY = points[i === points.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1].y;
    const subX = points[i === points.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1].x;
    const subY = points[i].y;
    area += addX * addY * 0.5 - subX * subY * 0.5;
  }
  if (absolute) {
    area = Math.abs(area);
  }
  return area;
}



/**
 * based on:  Justin C. Round's 
 * http://jsfiddle.net/justin_c_rounds/Gd2S2/light/
 */

function checkLineIntersection(p1, p2, p3, p4, exact = false) {
  // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
  let denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2;
  let intersectionPoint = {}

  denominator = ((p4.y - p3.y) * (p2.x - p1.x)) - ((p4.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p1.y));
  if (denominator == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  a = p1.y - p3.y;
  b = p1.x - p3.x;
  numerator1 = ((p4.x - p3.x) * a) - ((p4.y - p3.y) * b);
  numerator2 = ((p2.x - p1.x) * a) - ((p2.y - p1.y) * b);

  a = numerator1 / denominator;
  b = numerator2 / denominator;

  // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
  intersectionPoint = {
    x: p1.x + (a * (p2.x - p1.x)),
    y: p1.y + (a * (p2.y - p1.y))
  }

  let intersection = false;
  // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
  if ((a >= 0 && a <= 1) && (b >= 0 && b <= 1)) {
    intersection = true;
  }

  if (exact && !intersection) {
    return false;
  }

  // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
  return intersectionPoint;
};
path:hover {
  stroke: #9F1F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

text {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: white;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.6/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>

<p><button id="btnConvert">Convert</button></p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1260 1260" style="background: #f4f4f8;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <path id="lorem-ipsum"
            d="M19.6535 473.868C47.9918 363.089 105.946 262.111 187.302 181.761C268.658 101.41 370.349 44.7167 481.472 17.7586L494.995 73.5011C393.989 98.0047 301.557 149.536 227.608 222.571C153.659 295.606 100.982 387.39 75.2235 488.083L19.6535 473.868Z"
            fill="#58585A" stroke="white" stroke-width="10"  />
        <text>
            <textPath style="color: #fff;" xlink:href="#lorem-ipsum" startOffset="310" text-anchor="middle"
                dominant-baseline="central">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </textPath>
        </text>


        <path id="dolor-sit"
            d="M943.948 453.828C974.447 508.179 990.314 569.517 989.995 631.839C989.677 694.162 973.184 755.334 942.132 809.371C911.079 863.407 866.529 908.456 812.843 940.11C759.156 971.764 698.172 988.938 635.857 989.952C573.542 990.966 512.03 975.785 457.343 945.895C402.655 916.004 356.663 872.428 323.869 819.43C291.075 766.433 272.601 705.829 270.255 643.55C267.909 581.271 281.772 519.449 310.487 464.135L354.36 486.91C329.588 534.629 317.629 587.962 319.653 641.689C321.676 695.417 337.614 747.699 365.905 793.419C394.196 839.14 433.872 876.732 481.051 902.518C528.229 928.304 581.294 941.401 635.053 940.526C688.811 939.652 741.422 924.836 787.736 897.528C834.051 870.221 872.483 831.357 899.272 784.741C926.061 738.124 940.289 685.352 940.563 631.587C940.838 577.822 927.15 524.907 900.839 478.019L943.948 453.828Z"
            fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10"  />
        <text>
            <textPath xlink:href="#dolor-sit" startOffset="2175" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
                Dolor Sit
            </textPath>
        </text>
        <path id="amet"
            d="M476.668 407.763C521.185 377.048 573.901 360.411 627.985 360.008C682.069 359.604 735.028 375.452 779.999 405.5L749.393 451.307C713.598 427.391 671.445 414.776 628.396 415.097C585.348 415.418 543.388 428.661 507.954 453.109L476.668 407.763Z"
            fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" />
        <text>
            <textPath xlink:href="#amet" startOffset="160" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
                Amet
            </textPath>
        </text>

<h3>New Svg</h3>
<textarea  id="out"></textarea>



Far from perfect but it may help as a starting point.
The main concept:

parse all paths to a array of pathdata (I'm using Jarek Foksa's pathdata polyfill)
search for line commands and calculate the arcs center points as well as inner and outer radii. We retrieve inner and outer radius values from the extrapolated line intersection points.


3. Generate the new pathData based on these coordinates/values
In the example above we're generating a solid/closed shape as a background element to apply the white stroke/outline.
The textpath is an open path element with the same color as the original path but applied to the stroke attribute. The stroke width is calculated from the outer radius minus the inner radius.
We can now apply a startOffset="50%" to the open text path.
textPath vertical alignment
Another common problem is the visual orientation of text on path if the label get at the bottom of the circle. Ideally we could apply the side attribute to align text to the inside or outside of an arc. Unfortunately, this attribute is currently only supported by Firefox.
To alleviate this problem, we can switch drawing direction from clockwise to counterclockwise. This way we can ensure text is always rendered upright. (Most certainly not perfectly covered in the above helper)
Refactor charts dynamically
Frankly, the above example is quite insane if you're planning to add  and edit many new charts. So you should spend the time to find/develop a suitable generator library/script to generate subsequent charts. In the long run switching to a dedicated data-visualization library like d3 or investigating on script methods to create your own generator will most certainly pay off.
However, this approach can help simplify existing hard-coded charts.

Definitely a looks like a good starting point for if I need to generate the svg from dynamic values rather than an existing svg. I'm going to give chrwahl's solution a go first, but will definitely give your solution a go and reply to this/update my original question with this code if I get it working with queried start and end points etc. I did forget to put in the question that I'm developing a wind rose, just in case you're interested.

@Sam Ashley: Pardon me, my explanations might have been slightly confusing (as I intended to describe the calculation steps). In fact, the described helper function pathToArc() does all conversions for you – no dynamic values needed. Albeit not heavily tested so there are certainly edge cases where it may fail to reproduce the given segment path correctly. In other words: this helper tries to "reverse-engineer" a complex hard-coded pie-chart segment to a more compact representation (closed or single open path). So please feel free to post examples where it fails

However, you raise a good point: if you're planning to generate a lot of new charts, you should definitely consider find/developing a better generator script to suit your needs. You'll definitely find a lot of "recipes" on SO that use either dedicated data visualisation libraries like d3 or libraries focused on chart generation - as well as native JS approaches. Frankly, your current SVG code example is rather unusual  as it draws segment by a bunch of cubic beziers that could be simplified using a single a arcto command.

To center the text within the purple section of the SVG, you can adjust the startOffset attribute of the  elements.


<style type="text/css">
    path:hover {
        fill: #9F1F;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    svg > text {
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-weight: 600;
        fill: white;
    }
</style>
<svg width="540" height="540" viewBox="0 0 1260 1260" style="background: #f4f4f8;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="lorem-ipsum" d="M19.6535 473.868C47.9918 363.089 105.946 262.111 187.302 181.761C268.658 101.41 370.349 44.7167 481.472 17.7586L494.995 73.5011C393.989 98.0047 301.557 149.536 227.608 222.571C153.659 295.606 100.982 387.39 75.2235 488.083L19.6535 473.868Z" fill="#58585A" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-inside-1_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath style="color: #fff;" xlink:href="#lorem-ipsum" startOffset="370" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="dolor-sit" d="M943.948 453.828C974.447 508.179 990.314 569.517 989.995 631.839C989.677 694.162 973.184 755.334 942.132 809.371C911.079 863.407 866.529 908.456 812.843 940.11C759.156 971.764 698.172 988.938 635.857 989.952C573.542 990.966 512.03 975.785 457.343 945.895C402.655 916.004 356.663 872.428 323.869 819.43C291.075 766.433 272.601 705.829 270.255 643.55C267.909 581.271 281.772 519.449 310.487 464.135L354.36 486.91C329.588 534.629 317.629 587.962 319.653 641.689C321.676 695.417 337.614 747.699 365.905 793.419C394.196 839.14 433.872 876.732 481.051 902.518C528.229 928.304 581.294 941.401 635.053 940.526C688.811 939.652 741.422 924.836 787.736 897.528C834.051 870.221 872.483 831.357 899.272 784.741C926.061 738.124 940.289 685.352 940.563 631.587C940.838 577.822 927.15 524.907 900.839 478.019L943.948 453.828Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-6-inside-6_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#dolor-sit" startOffset="400" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Dolor Sit
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="amet" d="M476.668 407.763C521.185 377.048 573.901 360.411 627.985 360.008C682.069 359.604 735.028 375.452 779.999 405.5L749.393 451.307C713.598 427.391 671.445 414.776 628.396 415.097C585.348 415.418 543.388 428.661 507.954 453.109L476.668 407.763Z" fill="#9F1F63" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-11-inside-11_4_33)"/>
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#amet" startOffset="300" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
            Amet
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>




note the xlink: part is no longer required in SVG2

unfortunately this is not the effect I am going for. Whilst the startOffset attribute got me to my original attempt, this is not the final solution. The text should be within the purple/grey (green when highlighted) sections of the SVG path and not on the white border.
